# Unable to go to Localhost

Tags: joomla, localhost, wamp, wampserver

When I try to go to Localhost by entering http and then ://localhost, it automatically branches to http://naazir-pc/WebDB/WEBDB.home with a message saying "Oops! This link appears to be broken.". 
I ran "Start WampSever" and the status of the server says "WAMPSERVER - server Online"

I have closed Skype as well.

Can you please help me with this problem.

Thanks
Naazir Ajward

Comment: you must tap the ruby red shoe heels 3 times and say: "I want to go to localhost..." jk.  If you type http://localhost in your browser and you have a web server running on the default port 80 it will take that url and return its default page.  What were you hoping to get?

Comment: `naazir-pc` is probably your hostname. Don't worry, you're not being redirected outside your computer. Try updating WampServer, or another Apache/MySQL/PHP suite such as XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Not professional or even experienced in python but - 1)check page syntax 2)specify port, if not 80 - ex.: localhost:8080/WebDB/...
PS: begin with 2nd recommendation =)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help :) The Oracle_webdb_listener was running on port 80. That was the cause.